# how to create permalink to new category file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

as a newbie in wordpress i m searching over to create link of my 'new-category.php' file to display my product category only & 'category.php' will be default for others. So anyone please tell me how to change the default permalink to link-up my static 'new-category.php' file ?

Here below code displaying the default category page:

```
<?php $categories=getCategory ();
       foreach ($categories as $category)  {     ?>
<li> <a href=" <?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id );?>">
<?php   echo     $category->cat_name; ?> </a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your page like :

```
<?php /* Template Name: my_category*/ ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

    //my_category page

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and access it like `: http://yourdomain.com/my_category`

Template Name: plays important role here.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. its working for me but my question is i want display this my_category template once click 'product category' from sidebar list. have u got my point ?

Comment: I will definitely help you. pleas create new new question please.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660584/how-to-create-permalink-to-display-particular-category-page]