# How to create a permalink to display a particular category page

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

In my sidebar I have two categories: 'Product' and 'News'. So I have created two category files `category-product.php` and `category-news.php` to display them in a different way.

My question is: how can I create permalinks to display these separate category pages? The default permalink always displays the `category.php` file. Can anybody please provide some ideas? I'm very new to WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress selects template based on request parse results, not only on permalink structure.
When it determines that you request category page then it tries to find `category-$slug.php` file in theme folder. If this file is not found it tries to find `category-$id.php` and if it also absent, WP uses `category.php`.

So double check that `product` and `news` are categories slugs (not titles).
And try to use debug-bar plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/). It can show request parameters.

Comment: +1, and [this](http://wpmu.org/easily-apply-templates-to-your-wordpress-category-pages/) could also helpful for OP.